# How can I use the trackpad for the sliders like the stars of the Vita version of f & f 2nd?

Tags: steam-deck, steam-input, hatsune-miku-project-diva-mega-mix

On the PlayStation Vita version of Hatsune Miku Project Diva f and f 2nd, you have stars, which you activate by [moving your finger on the touch screen on any direction](https://youtu.be/MpmC98gIZlE?t=132).

Now that I have Hatsune Miku Project Diva Mega Mix+ on Steam and a Steam Deck, how can I make the slider behave as such with the touchpads?

In other words, I want to slide to the left or to the right on the touchpad to move the slider to the left or right, which corresponds to moving L and R to the left or right, and after I let my finger go it auto centers.

I tried setting the touchpads as analog sticks but they keep moving towards the direction, they don't auto center, and I don't understand most of the options.

Comment: I managed to get it to stop moving to a specific direction by disabling Trackball Mode. I still can't hold the sliders by starting in the center and holding a direction as it auto centers automatically even if I have the finger on the trackpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was confusing to get it working, but it was worth it as it makes things a bit easier on some songs that use fast slider switches like Ghost Rule.

By default, the stock layout is missing some binds, as it will be using the DualShock 4 profile. You can either load the Steam Controller profile or add those missing binds yourself (for me, select and the arrows were not binded on the first launch of the game).

Go to the Trackpad section of the controller settings. Here you will see two entries for the trackpads called JOYSTICK MOVE, where the first one corresponds to the left stick and the second one corresponds to the right stick. Assign the left trackpad to the first option and the right trackpad to the second option.

[image]

Now, disable the Vertical Axis by setting the Output Axis of both trackpads to Horizontal Only. This is very important as the trackpad will always send the input as 100%, which will make the game sometimes think that you are moving the trackpad up-down instead of left-right, giving you a MISS.

[image]